# My theme is adding an unmatched end tag and outputting it to my screen

Tags: themes, tags, child-theme

I use a theme that uses WPBakery - I have a feeling WPBakery might be the culprit here. I made a few small changes, and now this is appearing at the very top of the page, above the menu:

```
" />
```

I have included a screenshot for reference.

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated as I'm banging my head trying to figure out why

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't displaying before for some reason, but we did find that this exists in the original file. We went in and deleted it and it disappeared....the real mystery is why it suddenly started appearing in the first place. It's related to the char-set.

In any case, answer is solved, somewhat.